# Как правильно организовать приведение типа?

Tags: java

Имеется родительский класс и несколько произведенных из него классов. Объекты всех дочерних классов собраны в ArrayList. Мне необходимо по очереди извлекать объекты из ArrayList и в дальнейшем работать с ними в зависимости от того, представителем какого типа является извлеченный объект. Что то типа такого:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Parrent {
    int p = 1;
}

class A extends Parrent {
    A() {
          p = 10;
    }

    int a = 2;
}

class B extends Parrent {
    B() {
         p = 20;
    }
    int b = 3;
}

class C extends Parrent {
    C() {
          p = 30;
    }
    int c = 4;
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Parrent> par = new ArrayList<>();
        A x = new A();
        B y = new B();
        C z = new C();
        par.add(x);
        par.add(y);
        par.add(z);

        /*
        //works ok
        Parrent po = par.get(0);
        A poa = (A) po;
        System.out.println(poa.p);

        po = par.get(1);
        B pob = (B) po;
        System.out.println(pob.p);

        po = par.get(2);
        C poc = (C) po;
        System.out.println(poc.p);
        */

        /*
        //doesn't work (can't find symbol)
        for (int i = 0; i < par.size(); i++) {
            if (par.get(i) instanceof A) {
                A po = (A) par.get(i);
            } else if (par.get(i) instanceof B) {
                B po = (B) par.get(i);
            } else if (par.get(i) instanceof C) {
                C po = (C) par.get(i);
            }

            //can't find symbol po
            System.out.println(po.p);
            //do some stuff with po
        }
        */

    }
}
```

Первый закомментированный блок кода работает нормально. Но он, в силу понятных причин, не годится. А вот второй не работает. Компилятор не обнаруживает объект po. Как можно выйти из данной ситуации, т.е. на каждом этапе цикла получать объект с одним и тем же именем, но разного типа?

Comment: Все работает, у Вас переменная `po` находится внутри if, объявите эту переменную до первого if. Все дело в видимости переменной.

Comment: Вообще это плохая практика и явный каст, как правило, свидетельствует о том что у вас неверно задизайнено приложение. По вопросу, делаете проверку instanceof и приводите к нужному типу

Comment: `po` находиться в области видимости `if`. У вас два варианта, либо вы работаете с `po` в области видимости `if`, либо выше объявляете `po` с типом общего родителя и работаете с ним вне `if`. Третьего не дано.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
Parrent po = null;
for (int i = 0; i < par.size(); i++) {
            if (par.get(i) instanceof A) {
                po = par.get(i);
                System.out.println(((A)po).a);
            } else if (par.get(i) instanceof B) {
                po = par.get(i);
                System.out.println(((B)po).b);
            } else if (par.get(i) instanceof C) {
                po = par.get(i);
                System.out.println(((C)po).c);
            }

            System.out.println(po.p);
            //do some stuff with po
}
```

В сущности, в этом случае вам даже не обязательно делать приведение типов в цикле - после извлечения объекта из списка.

Comment: Нет так нельзя. Дело как раз в том и состоит, чтобы далее работать с переменной po как с одним из объектов A, B или C. Собственно для этого приведение и делается. Предложенный Вами вариант я пробовал, но он дает ошибку компилирования variable po is already defined

Comment: @vitaliy4us, у меня этот код работает, и компилятор ни на что не ругается. Вы точно вставили этот кусок кода вместо комментариев?

Comment: @vitaliy4us. и я обновила ответ - добавила пример того, как с po можно работать "как с одним из объектов A, B или C"

Comment: Нет, ибо так все эти ифы теряют всякий смысл и достаточно было бы только одной строки получения объекта ро типа Parrent. Мне же необходимо его привести к его реальному типу, а не родительскому. Поэтому делал в каждой строке оператора if приведение объекта к тому типу, которым он и является исходя из instanceof.

Comment: @vitaliy4us, в обновлённом варианте как раз и показано, как можно обратиться к полям, которых нет в родительском классе

Comment: Все дело в том, что за строчкой "//do some stuff with po" скрывается довольно большой кусок кода и дублировать его во всех ветках if не годится. Поэтому, хотелось бы после всех проверок получить готовый объект, с которым могли бы работать все одноименные методы, переопределенные в каждом из классов.

Comment: @vitaliy4us, а что вам мешает весь этот большой кусок кода разделить на три метода, и добавить вызов этих методов в блоки `if`, вместо `System.out.println(...);`?)

Comment: @vitaliy4us, и если вам нужно чтобы далее работали только одноименные методы, переопределенные в каждом из классов, которые есть и в родительском классе, то этот код будет работать и так

Comment: Смотрите, если мы например, объявим в родительском классе константу CONSTANT = 1000, а в дочерних ее же равной 2000, 3000, 4000, то код:

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < parr.size(); i++) {Parrent po = par.get(i); System.out.println(po.CONSTANT);} выведет на печать 3 раза тысячу, но не 2000, 3000, 4000

Comment: Хотя, пожалуй, Вы правы. Можно сделать переопределенный getConstant()

Comment: @vitaliy4us Вот именно - я писала про обращение к методам, а вы - про обращение к полям, это разные вещи :)

Answer (score 1):

Все работает, у Вас переменная `po` находится внутри if, объявите эту переменную до первого if, либо используйте элементы после приведения типа  внутри if. Все дело в видимости переменной.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Parrent> par = new ArrayList<Parrent>();
    A x = new A();
    B y = new B();
    C z = new C();
    par.add(x);
    par.add(y);
    par.add(z);

    for (int i = 0; i < par.size(); i++) {
        if (par.get(i) instanceof A) {
            A po = (A) par.get(i);
            System.out.println(po.p);
            System.out.println(po.a); //поле a Класса A
        } else if (par.get(i) instanceof B) {
            B po = (B) par.get(i);
            System.out.println(po.p);
            System.out.println(po.b); //поле b Класса B
        } else if (par.get(i) instanceof C) {
            C po = (C) par.get(i);
            System.out.println(po.p);
            System.out.println(po.c); //поле с Класса С
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, так я уже пробовал, компилятор говорит, что такая переменная уже была объявлена.

Comment: Обновил ответ. У Вас значит объявлена выше переменная `po`, на нее и ругается, у меня она объявляется внутри if, и можно использовать конкретные поля a,b,c нужного класса

Comment: Но ведь это точно то же с чего мы и начали (т.е вариант из моего вопроса). Я понимаю, что в нем каждой ветке if можно было бы использовать поля соответствующего класса. Но задача состоит в другом - после проверок получить объект соответствующего типа. И использовать один и тот же код не n раз в каждой ветке if, а один раз после проверок, присвоив ему нужный тип.

Comment: Вопрос состоял в приведении типов, и ответы уже даны. По Вашему комментарию вопрос, зачем приводить объект к нужному типу? Лучше всего использовать тип `Parrent`, для получения полей, общих для всех объектов и работать с ними, а когда нужно будет использовать конкретные поля, то только тогда и приводить к нужному типу.